# Math::GMP errors when installing

Tags: perl, gmp

Im trying to install `Math::GMP` but it keeps failing and im not sure where to go from here .  This is what im typing and here is the output pointing to the log file:

```
[root@confeng Math-GMP-2.06-VEVNp7]# cpanm Math::GMP
--> Working on Math::GMP
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TU/TURNSTEP/Math-GMP-2.06.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-GMP-2.06 ... OK
Building and testing Math-GMP-2.06 ... FAIL
! Installing Math::GMP failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
[root@confeng Math-GMP-2.06-VEVNp7]#
```

I checked the logs and im not sure what structure im supposed to have
here are the logs of `/root/.cpanm/build.log`

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.5011 on perl 5.008008 built for i386-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1336128898.6464
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching Math::GMP on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Math::GMP
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TU/TURNSTEP/Math-GMP-2.06.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Math-GMP-2.06.tar.gz
Entering Math-GMP-2.06
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Configuring Math-GMP-2.06
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Math::GMP
-> OK
Finding PREREQ from Makefile ...
Building and testing Math-GMP-2.06
cp lib/Math/GMP.pm blib/lib/Math/GMP.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Math/GMP.pm (blib/lib/auto/Math/GMP)
/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -      typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  GMP.xs > GMP.xsc && mv GMP.xsc GMP.c
gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/inc$
GMP.xs:4:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
GMP.xs: In function âconstantâ:
GMP.xs:49: warning: label ânot_thereâ defined but not used
GMP.c: In function âXS_Math__GMP_new_from_scalarâ:
GMP.c:93: error: âmpz_tâ undeclared (first use in this function)
GMP.c:93: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
GMP.c:93: error: for each function it appears in.)
GMP.c:93: error: âRETVALâ undeclared (first use in this function)
GMP.xs:70: warning: implicit declaration of function âmpz_init_set_strâ
GMP.c: In function âXS_Math__GMP_new_from_scalar_with_baseâ:
GMP.c:114: error: âmpz_tâ undeclared (first use in this function)
GMP.c:114: error: âRETVALâ undeclared (first use in this function)
GMP.c: In function âXS_Math__GMP_destroyâ:
GMP.c:133: error: âmpz_tâ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Answer (score 13):

> GMP.xs:4:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory

is the important part.

You must install the development files/headers for libgmp. On my openSUSE system the relevant file is `/usr/include/gmp.h`, the package is called `gmp-devel`. On Debian/derived systems, the package is called `libgmp3-dev`.

Comment: If the proposal [Easy installation of non-CPAN dependencies](http://news.perlfoundation.org/2012/05/2012q2-grant-proposal-easy-ins.html) by [chorny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13467/alexandr-ciornii) is granted and completed, these sort of beginner problems will dwindle drastically. Community, please share this.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu box, I installed libmath-gmp-perl by Synaptic Package Manager.  The GMP package in question would be compiled.  It's not a good workaround though, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

run this command :

```
yum install gmp-static
```